# Finding average and totalNum in Python Class

Tags: python, list, class

I'm trying to write a program in Python using classes for the first time and have figured it out for the most part. The only thing that stumps me in this program, is how to tally the number of students that were created for the program. I thought I could just create a variable "numStudents" and just do the ole "x = x + 1" but it doesn't work with classes for some reason. Anyone know a solution? I also need to calculate the average age and my list doesn't seem to be working.

```
numStudents = 0
ageList = list()
class student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, stuID, age):
        self.name = name
        self.stuID = stuID
        self.age = age
    def student_display(self):
        numStudents = numStudents + 1
        stuID = str(self.stuID)
        age = str(self.age)
        ageList.append(self.age)
        print "This student's name is " + self.name + ", his student ID is " + stuID + ", and his age is " + age + "."

student1 = student("Justin", 10001, 21)
student2 = student("Charles", 10002, 23)
student3 = student("Erik", 10003, 20)
student4 = student("The Doctor", 99999, 22)
student5 = student("Steven", 10004, 21)
student6 = student("Melissa", 10005, 19)
student7 = student("Sarah", 10006, 21)
student8 = student("Eren", 10007, 18)
students = 0                                           #Can't figure out how to get rid of the "NONE" that keeps printing after every statement

print student1.student_display()
print student2.student_display()
print student3.student_display()
print student4.student_display()
print student5.student_display()
print student6.student_display()
print student7.student_display()
print student8.student_display()

print "There are " + numStudents + " students in the class."
average = 0
sum = 0
for n in ageList:
    sum = sum + n
average = sum/len(ageList)
print "The average age in the class is " + average + "."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get a `None` printout is that you're printing the return value of `student_display`, which is `None` since it doesn't return anything. You already do the printing inside the method, no need to do it again.

The reason that your `num_students` and `ageLists` doesn't work is that you need to add a `global` keyword in `student_display`:

```
def student_display(self):
    global numStudents
    global ageLists
    numStudents = numStudents + 1
```

But, having said that, it's really poor practice to do it like this. There are a number of ways to solve the problem, but for the `numStudents` case, you could simply have a list of students you construct like so:

```
students = [
            student("Justin", 10001, 21),
            ...
            student("Eren", 10007, 18)]
```

Then print all of the students like so:

```
for student in students:
    student.student_display()
```

And for calculating the average age:

```
ages = [student.age for student in students]
print('Average Age Is: {}'.format(sum(ages)/len(ages))
```

Comment: Wow that was incredibly helpful and insightful. Thank you!